# 800px of WhiteSpace

Tags: css, wordpress

http://vandapaint.planb-creativeonline.co.uk/inspiration/

I added a Grid Plugin I have asked the question to the Developers but awaiting a reply.

There is 800px of negative space causing horizontal scrollbars. It is only on the page with the plugin which also has a lightbox.

I have been through the CSS with Developer Tools and there is no obvious solution. It is not the menu as is fine on all other pages.

Any help appreciated!!

Ant

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Difficult when the problem was possible anywhere on the page. Below answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, it's difficult, however not impossible. And part of debugging your issue is to eliminate the unnecessary chunks of code and whittle it down to a bare minimum example. Often doing this alone will help you find the issue.

Comment: Thank-you!!! Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your `#inspiretitle`. It has `left: 400px;` on it, and as a block element, it will extend off the page. Try getting rid of that positioning and just add `text-align: center;`

```
#inspiretitle {
    left: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I had it connected to animate-on-scroll plugin which I have now deactivated this then affected the positioning.